# Doctrine: can the same attribute make a relation to two different destination attributes?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-one

Is this OneToOne relation possible with Doctrine (in Symfony)?

```
User                     Time
+----------+             +-------+
| ...      |             | ...   |
| time_id  |o-----+-----o| user  |
|          |      |      | ...   |
| time2_id |o-----+      | type  |
| ...      |             +-------+
+----------+
```

That is, a User can potentially have two different Time entities associated to it:
one of type=0 and the other one of type=1.

I could have splitted Time in two different entities, but I thought that this way I
could spare replicating some code, as Time entity has an eventListener and more code associated...

I have coded it like this:

```
class Time
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="time, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="time2", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $user;
...}

class User
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Time::class, inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="time_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Time::class, inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="time2_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $time2;
...}
```

And in fact I am flawlessly using it, but Symfony silently complains (in **Symfony toolbar/Doctrine/Entities Mapping > Mapping errors**) with:

```
    App\Entity\User     

    The mappings App\Entity\User#time2 and App\Entity\Time#user are inconsistent with each other.
```

Obviously, Doctrine doesn't like the second **@ORM\OneToOne** on **$user**, and is discarding it.

What hypotethical misbehaviours could this code lead to?

Note: doctrine/common v2.11

Comment: There is nothing hypothetical. Doctrine is discarding part of your configuration, because it's wrong. And since using an incorrect configuration is logically not defined, today it's ignoring the second one, but it could plausible happen that on some upgrade it will start upgrading the first one, or both of them. Just use correct mappings and save yourself some headaches.

Comment: And no, you can't use the same property for two different relationships (unless is some kind of inheritance mapping, but that's not what you are about here).

Comment: I suspected this, but the other solution is duplicating the Time entity, and this leads to more duplicated code: I just thought this double relation could be possible... :-(

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it is possible to make this relation, as far as one renounces to make a [Bidirectional Association](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/unitofwork-associations.html):

```
User                     Time
+----------+             +-------+
| ...      |             | ...   |
| time_id  |o-----+-----o|       |
|          |      |      |       |
| time2_id |o-----+      | type  |
| ...      |             +-------+
+----------+
```

implemented by:

```
class Time
{
...
}

class User
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Time::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="time_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Time::class, cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="time2_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $time2;
...}
```

Also [look at this link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/owning-vs-inverse) for **Owning vs Inverse relations**.

In my case, this totally fits my needs, as the inverse part is for methods like:

`$Time->getUser();`

which I can prescind of.